# No puedo Enviar mis datos de una tabla dinamica en C# mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvc

Buenas tengo una pregunta. No puedo enviar los datos ingresados por el usuario en mi tabla dinámica a mi **controlador MVC** y **C#** en mi vista tengo lo siguiente:

Función que crea la tabla Dinámica:

```
function fn_agregar() {
   cadena = "<tr>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><input style='font - size: 20px; font - weight: 700;' class='form - control' type='text' name='COD_CLASIFICADOR[]' value='" + alias("#COD_CLASIFICADOR").val() + "' readonly required></td>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><input style='font - size: 20px; font - weight: 700;' class='form - control' type='text' name='COD_ITEM[]' value='" + alias("#COD_ITEM").val() + "' readonly required></td>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><input style='font - size: 20px; font - weight: 700;' class='form - control' type='text' name='NOMBRE[]' value='" + alias("#NOMBRE").val() + "' readonly required></td>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><input style='font - size: 20px; font - weight: 700;' class='form - control' type='text' name='VALOR_UNITARIO[]' value='" + alias("#VALOR_UNITARIO").val() + "' readonly required></td>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><input style='font - size: 20px; font - weight: 700;' class='form - control' type='text' id='CANTIDAD2' name='CANTIDAD[]' value='" + alias("#CANTIDAD").val() + "' readonly required></td>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><input style='font - size: 20px; font - weight: 700;' class='form - control' type='text' name='VALOR_BRUTO[]' value='" + alias("#VALOR_BRUTO").val() + "' readonly required></td>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><input style='font - size: 20px; font - weight: 700;' class='form - control' type='text' name='VALOR_TOTAL[]' value='" + alias("#VALOR_TOTAL").val() + "' readonly required></td>";
   cadena = cadena + "<td><a class='elimina'><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button'><span class='fa fa-remove'></span></button></a></td>";
        alias("#detalles tbody").append(cadena);
   fn_eliminar();
   sumar();
   limpiar();    
};

function limpiar() {
   document.getElementById("COD_CLASIFICADOR").value = "";
   document.getElementById("COD_ITEM").value = "";
   document.getElementById("NOMBRE").value = "";
   document.getElementById("VALOR_UNITARIO").value = "";
   document.getElementById("CANTIDAD").value = "";
   document.getElementById("VALOR_BRUTO").value = "";
   document.getElementById("VALOR_TOTAL").value = "";
}

function fn_eliminar() {
   alias("a.elimina").click(function () {
      valor = alias(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(5).html();
         alias(this).parents("tr").fadeOut("normal", function () {
         alias(this).remove();
         restar();
      })
   });
};
```

La función que envía los datos

```
//Collect Multiple Order List For Pass To Controller
   alias("#saveOrder").click(function (e) {
      debugger;
      e.preventDefault();

      // var orderArr = [];
      // orderArr.length = 0;

      var orderArr = new Array;
      alias.each(alias("#detalles tbody"), function () {
         orderArr.push({
            COD_CLASIFICADOR: alias(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
            COD_ITEM: alias(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
            VALOR_UNITARIO: alias(this).find('td:eq(3)').html(),
            CANTIDAD: alias(this).find('td:eq(4)').html(),
            VALOR_BRUTO: alias(this).find('td:eq(5)').html(),
            VALOR_TOTAL: alias(this).find('td:eq(6)').html()
         });
      });

//After Click Save Button Pass All Data View To Controller For Save Database
   function saveOrder(data) {
      return alias.ajax({
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'POST',
         url: "/Cotizacion/Create",
         data: data,
         success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            location.reload();
         },
         error: function () {
            alert("Error!")    }
         });
      };

      var data = JSON.stringify(orderArr);

      alias.when(saveOrder(data)).then(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
      }).fail(function (err) {
         console.log(err);
      });
   });
```

Mi controlador

```
public JsonResult Create(CB_COTIZACION cB_COTIZACION, Detalle[] data)
{
   foreach (var item in data)
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         cB_COTIZACION.NUM_COTIZACION = cb_cotizazion;
         cB_COTIZACION.COD_CLIENTE = cB_COTIZACION.COD_CLIENTE;
         cB_COTIZACION.COD_VENDEDOR = cB_COTIZACION.COD_VENDEDOR;
         cB_COTIZACION.VALOR_BRUTO = item.VALOR_BRUTO;
         cB_COTIZACION.VALOR = item.VALOR_TOTAL;
      }
    );
    db.CB_COTIZACION.Add(cB_COTIZACION);
```

En el Modelo

```
{
   public class MVCJsonPost
   {
   }

   public class Detalle
   {
      public string COD_CLASIFICADOR { get; set; }
      public string COD_ITEM { get; set; }
      public decimal VALOR_UNITARIO { get; set; }
      public int CANTIDAD { get; set; }
      public decimal VALOR_BRUTO { get; set; }
      public decimal VALOR_TOTAL { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu controlador deberías poder pasar los datos asi,aunque al llamar al metodo del controlador le estás pasando dos variables que al hacer la petición en ajax,no lo pones.Para recibir los datos en el parámetro `data`,tendras que modificar un poco tu método para que lo reciba desde el body:

`[Route("Cotizacion/Create")]
        [HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(CB_COTIZACION cB_COTIZACION,[System.Web.Http.FromBody]Detalle[] data)
{
   foreach (var item in data)
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         cB_COTIZACION.NUM_COTIZACION = cb_cotizazion;
         cB_COTIZACION.COD_CLIENTE = cB_COTIZACION.COD_CLIENTE;
         cB_COTIZACION.COD_VENDEDOR = cB_COTIZACION.COD_VENDEDOR;
         cB_COTIZACION.VALOR_BRUTO = item.VALOR_BRUTO;
         cB_COTIZACION.VALOR = item.VALOR_TOTAL;
      }
    );
    db.CB_COTIZACION.Add(cB_COTIZACION);`

Espero que te sirva de ayuda